# Matrices - Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

An nxn matrix A has two identical rows. Explain why this means columns of A can not be linearly independent.

I think it is because number of equations is less than the number of variables?

Comment: You weren't given any system of equations to consider, so "because number of equations is less than the number of variables" isn't a correct answer.  Perhaps you might be able to setup a system of equations and then answer the question based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By row reduction you can transform the matrix into a matrix with only zeros in the first row. The determinant of this matrix is $0$ (simply to show with Laplace Theorem), hence the column vectors are linearly dependent as the matrix is not invertible.